# "Automatic Activation of Button & Persistent State: Implementing Responsive Navigation in React"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-navigation

"I have a challenge in React and I need help to achieve a specific functionality with a button. Currently, the button has an initial state of false, but I want it to automatically activate and display a navigation component (nav) when the screen resolution exceeds 768px.

Furthermore, if I am on a resolution lower than 768px and click on the button, it should maintain its true state regardless of changing back to a higher resolution.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a solution or guidance on how to implement this functionality in my React project. Thank you in advance for the help and support!"

//Button

```
    import React from "react";
import "../styleSheets/HamburgerMenu.css";

const HamburgerMenu = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`menu ${open ? "menu__active" : ""}`} 
      onClick={() => {
        setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
      }}
    >
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined menu__icon">
        {open ? "close" : "menu"} 
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default HamburgerMenu;
```

//Nav

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styleSheets/Nav.css";
import { links } from "./Data";
import HamburgerMenu from "./HamburgerMenu";

const Nav = () => {
  const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 600 && isNavOpen) {
        setIsNavOpen(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, [isNavOpen]);
  // Metodo para colorcar texto e iconos en el menu
  const LinkItem = ({ text, icon }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined icon-img">{icon}</span>
        <span className="icon-text">{text}</span>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <HamburgerMenu open={isNavOpen} setOpen={setIsNavOpen} />
      {/* Metodo para cerrar y abrir el menu */}
      <nav
        class={`toggle-menu ${
          isNavOpen ? "toggle-menu__open" : "toggle-menu__close"
        }`}
      >
        {/* <div className="toggle-menu__logo">the company logo</div> */}
        <ul className="toggle-menu__list">
          {links.map((links) => (
            <li>
              <a href="" className="toggle-menu__link">
                <LinkItem text={links.text} icon={links.icon} />
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new React project to test.
So you can check my code in React Empty project.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(window.innerWidth > 768);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            if (clicked) {
                setShowNav(true);
            } else {
                if (window.innerWidth < 768 && clicked) {
                    setShowNav(true);
                } else if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
                    setShowNav(false);
                } else {
                    setShowNav(true);
                }
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, [clicked, showNav]);

    function handleClick() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            setClicked(true);
        }
        setShowNav(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick} disabled={showNav}>
                Show Navigation
            </button>
            {showNav && <nav>Navigation Component</nav>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nice. I am very happy so that you get a good result.

Comment: Hello. @Jorge Leonardo.
If you are feeling good to my assistance, please click check mark and vote me.